# remove trailing zeros from a pipe delimited file in unix

Tags: unix

I have a pipedelimited file , there are few fields with decimals , I need to ignore zeros after decimal point in any field and redirect the output to a different file , there may be few decimal columns like column A as seen below

```
column A
24.4400
.8930
1.6730
.2200
1.6870
```

**expected output**

```
24.44
0.893
1.673
0.22
1.687
```

Suppose below is the pipe delimited file

```
080|580||185.50|12|0|24.4400|2014-06-09|20140531
080|580||185.20|12|0|700.00|2014-06-09|20140531
080|580||185.30|12|0|30.500|2014-06-09|20140531
```

**expected output** should be

```
080|580||185.5|12|0|24.44|2014-06-09|20140531
080|580||185.2|12|0|700|2014-06-09|20140531
080|580||185.3|12|0|30.5|2014-06-09|20140531
```

Can anyone please helpme in finding a solution for this , it should check any decimal fields and remove trailing zeros from those fields and output should be redirected to a different file

if the above is not possible 
then I am looking for a solution atleast on the below

since I know the position of the decimal fields , is there any way I can specify those particular fields in a unix command and remove trailing zeros from those fields and redirect the output to a new file , I would appreciate if anyone can find a solution for this

Comment: I can't think of why you would need to do this. Can you explain, or is this a learning exercise? Good luck.

Comment: Could you use python? Much more direct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk for this task:

```
$ awk -F\| '{$4=sprintf("%g",$4);$7=sprintf("%g",$7)}1' OFS="|" file
```

`sprintf("%g",$7)` : to print the shortest representation or float.

Comment: You can directly say `{$4=$4+0; $7=$7+0}1`. It will automatically convert to number, so that trailing zeros will leave.

Comment: I just notice that removing trailing zeros is useless here , can do it with just the mask, i like your solution also @fedorqui

Answer (score 1):

What about this awk?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$4=$4+0; $7=$7+0}1' file
080|580||185.5|12|0|24.44|2014-06-09|20140531
080|580||185.2|12|0|700|2014-06-09|20140531
080|580||185.3|12|0|30.5|2014-06-09|20140531
```

It is an idiomatic way to convert the 4th and 7th fields into number, so that the trailing 0s disappear.

Note the key point is to do an arithmetic operation in the field. And as we want the value to keep as it is, anything like `+0`, `/0` (if no `0`) or `*1` makes it.

Comment: I kind of prefer `$4=$4+0` to keep it more clear. But I like your idea, thanks @klashxx !